# How to differentiate between factory objects and functions?

Tags: javascript

I learnt that one way objects could be created in JavaScript (factory function) is as follows:

```
var newPerson=function(name){  
    var result = new Object();  
    result.name = name;  
    result.getName = function(){  
        return this.name;  
    };  
    return result;  
}; 


var personOne = newPerson("Diego");  
var personTwo = newPerson("Gangelo");  

console.log(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
console.log(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```

Well, I found somewhere that a function could be created as follows:

```
var hello = new Function('alert("Hello, World!");');
```

So how could I know an object from a function if they're declared in the same manner?

Answer (score 2):

> *"how could i know an object from a function if they're declared in the same manner?"*

Well... since the `Function` constructor returns `function` objects, you could simply use `typeof` to test it .

```
typeof hello === "function"; // true

typeof personOne === "function"; // false
```

---

The "factory function" is just a fancy term for a function you wrote that returns a new object. It's an alternate way of creating an object from using an object constructor.

So if I want a function that creates new objects, I can use a function as a constructor, which requires that I invoke it with `new`:

```
function MyObj() {
    this.foo = "bar"
}

var o = new MyObj();
```

---

Or I could use this "factory" pattern:

```
function MyObj() {
    return {
        foo: "bar"
    }
}

var o2 = MyObj();
```

---

Both of them create a new object, but the first way gives you an extra prototype object that you can extend without affecting other objects.

Neither of these approaches make a function object.

---

JavaScript has built in constructors for creating native objects and primitives. Constructors like:

- `Function`
- `Array`
- `Object`
- `RegExp`

...and so on.

These are built in to the environment, and can be used to create new native data. But JS also gives you the ability to build your own constructors. That's what I did in the example above.

Your own constructor returns an Object, but again, it is linked to a clean `prototype` object that can be extended for all objects created from that constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, the line

```
var hello = new Function('alert("Hello, World!");');
```

is essentially the same as

```
var hello = function() { alert("Hello, World!"); };
```

...except for some complications around binding. In practice, there's almost never any reason to use `new Function(...)`.

You can tell what kind of object you're dealing with using a couple of options:

- `typeof` provides a fairly gross indication (in this case, `"object"` vs. `"function"`).
- `Object.prototype.toString.call(whatever)` gives you more information by (for objects defined by the spec) giving you strings like `[object Object]` or `[object Function]` or `[object Array]`.

More in my blog post [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html) which deals with figuring out what things are in JavaScript (and why you rarely actually need to).